# problema con la ejecucion del de ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

cordial saludo

Buenos dias tengo un problema estoy trabajando con ajax pero cuando doy click en registrar no pasa nada, en el formulario

```js
    function NuevoUsuario(Name,Last_name,Email,User,Pass,Perfil,Estado)
    {
        var Name=$('#nombre').val();
        var Last_name=$('#apellido').val();
        var Email=$('#email').val();
        var User=$('#usuario').val();
        var Pass=$('#pass').val();
        var Perfil=$('#perfil').val();
        var Estado=$('#estado').val();
        var mData={
            Name:Name,
            Last_name:Last_name,
            Email:Email,
            User:User,
            Pass:Pass,
            Perfil:Perfil,
            Estado:Estado
        };
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"../controller/add.php",
            data:mData,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(r){
                if(r.add){
                    swal.fire(
                        'Se ha Registro Usuario',
                        'success'
                    )+r.msg;
                }else{
                    swal.fire(
                        'Error de registro',
                        'error'
                    )+r.msg;
                }
            }
        });
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sistema de Notas</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../../public/img/engranaje.png" type="img/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/sidebar.css">
    
    <script src="js/Users.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav flex-column shadow d-flex sidebar mobile-hid" style="background-color: rgb(45,44,43);">
        <li class="nav-item logo-holder">
            <div class="text-center text-white logo py-4 mx-4"><a class="active text-white text-decoration-none" id="title" href="#"><strong>Sidebar</strong></a><a class="text-white float-right" id="sidebarToggleHolder" href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars" id="sidebarToggle"></i></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active text-left text-white py-1 px-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt mx-3"></i><span class="text-nowrap mx-2">Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-left text-white py-1 px-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user mx-3"></i><span class="text-nowrap mx-2">Mis Calificaciones</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-left text-white py-1 px-0" href="#"><i class="far fa-life-ring mx-3"></i><span class="text-nowrap mx-2">Estudiantes</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-left text-white py-1 px-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-archive mx-3"></i><span class="text-nowrap mx-2">Archive</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-left text-white py-1 px-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar mx-3"></i><span class="text-nowrap mx-2">Statistics</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link text-left text-white py-1 px-0 position-relative" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
         <i class="fas fa-user-edit mx-3"></i></i><span class="fa fa-check-square-o mx-2">Mis Calificaciones</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down float-none float-lg-right fa-sm">
              
            </i></a>
            <div
                class="dropdown-menu border-0 animated fadeIn" role="menu"><a class="dropdown-item text-white" role="presentation" href="../../Calificaciones/Pages/add.php"> <span>Calificación</span></a><a class="dropdown-item text-white" role="presentation" href="../../Calificaciones/Pages/edit.php"><span>calificaciones</span></a><a class="dropdown-item text-white" role="presentation"
                    href="#"><span>More</span></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link text-left text-white py-1 px-0 position-relative" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
            <i class="far fa-life-ring  mx-3"></i><span class="text-nowrap mx-2">Estudiantes</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down float-none float-lg-right fa-sm">
              
            </i></a>
            <div
                class="dropdown-menu border-0 animated fadeIn" role="menu"><a class="dropdown-item text-white" role="presentation" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> <span>Nuevo Estudiante</span></a><a class="dropdown-item text-white" role="presentation" href="#"><span>Change email</span></a><a class="dropdown-item text-white" role="presentation"
                    href="#"><span>More</span></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-left text-white py-1 px-0" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt mx-3"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-right d-none position-absolute"></i><span class="text-nowrap mx-2">Log out</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper" class="w-100 bg-light-blue">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark border-bottom">
          <div class="container"></div>
  
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   <font color="white"><b><?php 
                    $Usuario=$_SESSION['nom'];
                    echo strtoupper($Usuario);
                  ?> <i class="ion-gear-a"></i>
                  </a>
                  </b>
                 </font> 
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ion-edit"></i> <b>Perfil</b>  </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="../../Usuarios/Controller/cerrarSesion.php"> <i class="ion-android-exit"></i> <b>Cerrar Sesion</b>  </a>
                 </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

       
            
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around mt-5">
            <div class="card col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
               <article class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-4 mt-1 text-center">Registro de Usuario</h4>
               </article>
                <form id="frmUsers" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin:auto;">
                        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Apellido</label>
                         <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Correo Electronico</label>
                         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electronico">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Usuario</label>
                         <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Password</label>
                         <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="******">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="estado">Perfil:</label> 
                    <select name="perfil" id="perfil" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione perfil de usuario</option>
                        <option value="1">admnistrador</option>
                        <option value="2">docente</option>
                        <option value="2">estudiante</option>
                    </select> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="estado">Estado:</label> 
                        <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione estado del usuario</option>
                            <option value="1">Activo</option>
                            <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <button  class="bt btn-success btn-block" id="btnGuardar" >Registrarse</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    


    <script src="../../public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../public/js/sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
    $('#btnGuardar').click(function()
    {
       NuevoUsuario();         
    });
 });
</script>
```

codigo php model agregaUsuario

```
public function addUsuarios($Name,$Last_Name,$Email,$User,$Pass,$Perfil,$Estado)
        {
            $statement= $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,last_name,email,usuario,password,perfil,estado) VALUES 
            (:name,:last_name,:email,:user,:pass,:perfil,:estado)");
            //encriptación de clave usando algortimo de encriptacion hash
            $Pass_cifrado=password_hash($Pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $statement->bindParam(':name',$Name);
            $statement->bindParam(':last_name',$Last_Name);
            $statement->bindParam(':email',$Email);
            $statement->bindParam(':user',$User);
            $statement->bindParam(':pass',$Pass_cifrado);
            $statement->bindParam(':perfil',$Perfil);
            $statement->bindParam(':estado',$Estado);
            if($statement->execute() && $statement->rowCount()>0){
                $r=array("add"=>true,"msg"=>"se han agregado los datos:".$statement->rowCount());
                header('Location:../Pages/add.php');
              }else{
                  $r=array("msg"=>"No se agregaron los datos");
              }
              echo json_encode($r);
        }
```

[image: no esta funcionando es script correctamente me lleva los datos pero no realiza el registro]

```
verifico el script todo parece correcto pero no hace nada solo recarga la pagina
```

> [![cambios realizado pero no me sale nada solo me recarga la pagina y
> nada anexo codigo en la pagina button estoy realizando el evento
> onclick="NuevoUsuario();"][2]][2]
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/levRM.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxoQd.png   [2]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2BDk.png

pongo tal cual la información como estan comentando pero no pasa nada me sale lo mismo si no que ahora la informacion en url como se muestra a continuación
[image: no hace nada mas a pesar de que todo el procedimiento esta como se indica]

Comment: Saludos. En el `success` del **Ajax** aplica `console.log(r)` para que veas que recibes. En el PHP `agregaUsuario` "completa" `$r=array("msg"=>"No se agregaron los datos");` que tambien devuelva `"add"=>false`; ya que si falla no existe en la respuesta a la petición Ajax. Particularmente yo, no coloco instrucciones `header` devuelvo solo el resultado de `json_encode`.

Comment: como te dicen Pon un alert despues del success para ver que retorna y lo mejor es retornar un json codificado el el php para interpretarlo en el ajax

Comment: En la función `$('#btnGuardar').click(function()` antes de llamar `NuevoUsuario();` agrega `event.preventDefault();` para evitar que se recargue la página.